# How can i ask for class type of inner class?

Tags: java

I have an inner class B and create an anonymous instance of it. How can I ask for class type B? System out is false for `getClass (), getEnclosingClass ()`...

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = new B() {}.getClass();
        System.out.println("" + (clazz == B.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not creating an instance of `B`, you're creating an instance of an anonymous subclass of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
Class clazz = new B() {}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
```

Javadoc states

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity
>   (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.

When you create an anonymous inner class, you are extending the class itself and therefore its class is different form the parent, it's a sub class.